# How to use node package vue-tweet-embed in vuejs2?

Tags: javascript, npm, vue.js, vuejs2

I am not getting that how to use [vue-tweet-embed](http://github.com/tonickkozlov/vue-tweet-embed) in vue file. it's shows error like:

> Unknown custom element:  - did you register the component
>   correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name"
>   option

---

> Home.vue

```
  <template>
    <Tweet :id="'783943172057694208'"></Tweet>
  </template>

  <script>
  import Vue from 'vue'
  import Tweet from 'vue-tweet-embed'

  export default {
    data() {
      return {

      }
    },
    components: {'component-view': Tweet},
    created(){

    },
    methods: {

    }
  }
  </script>
  <style scoped>

  </style>
```

Comment: Provide code, this is not enough.

Comment: Change this `components: {'component-view': Tweet},` to just this `components: {Tweet},`

Comment: @BelminBedak thanks for reply, 
i am Not getting error, but also not getting any output.

Comment: Well are you sure that this tweed id is valid ?

Comment: @BelminBedak It's a valid tweet. Your suggestion works in a clean project. Or he could change `<Tweet></Tweet>` to `<component-view></component-view>`.

Comment: @BelminBedak i am still not getting. can you send me code snippet.
from where it needs to be import/export.
i am using https://github.com/auth0-blog/vue-jwt-authentication template.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the parent page where you are using this component:

```
  <template>
    <span>
      <component-view :id="'783943172057694208'"></component-view>
    </span>
  </template>

  <script>
  import Vue from 'vue'
  import Tweet from 'vue-tweet-embed'

  export default {
    data() {
      return {

      }
    },
    components: {
      // component-view is available in the parents scope
      'component-view': Tweet
    },
    created(){

    },
    methods: {

    }
  }
  </script>
```

The 'component-view' is available in the parent scope.

Comment: thanks for reply. i am still not getting. can you send me code snippet. from where it needs to be import/export. i don't know what am i missing. and i have spend many time. i am using http://github.com/auth0-blog/vue-jwt-authentication template. is there any problem with template? or i need to use other? then which can be used?

Comment: I used vue-cli https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli and had setup a dummy project with above component. It worked. The vue-embed-component works with vue2 and your vue-jwt-authentication is vue 1.0.

Comment: ok, but i have installed 2+ with it.
but i will try with vue-cli also.
thanks @Deepak

Comment: Can any one tell me how can i display message or image if tweet is deleted or not avialable?